# Dialog shows up several times (Does FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen stay in memory after AppLifecycleState.paused/inactive in flutter?)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, backend, flutter-alertdialog, password-less

I have "*Email link sign-in (Passwordless)*" in my app. It works as expected. But there is one issue that the `catchError` on `_auth.signInWithEmailLink(email: userEmail, emailLink: link.toString())`  is called several times (e.g. if I go to my email, use an expired action code for the 4th time, when it navigates to the app, it opens 4 dialogs for that error).

Here is the code in didChangeAppLifecycleState

```
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLink) {
    final Uri? deepLink = dynamicLink.link;

    emailLinkService.handleLink(
        deepLink!, _emailController.text, context, state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => !(route is PopupRoute));
    }
  }, onError: (e) async {
    print(e);
  });

  final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  final Uri? deepLink = data?.link;

  if (deepLink != null) {
    emailLinkService.observableLink = deepLink.toString();
  }
}
```

And here is the `handleLink` method:

```
class EmailLinkService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future handleLink(Uri link, userEmail, BuildContext context, state) async {
  if (_auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link.toString())) {
    _auth
        .signInWithEmailLink(email: userEmail, emailLink: link.toString())
        .catchError((onError) {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        PlatformAlertDialog(
          title: onError.code,
          content: onError.message ?? onError.toString(),
          defaultActionText: Strings.ok,
        ).show(context);
      }
      print(
          '>>>> email link service > handleLink > Error signing in with email link $onError');
    });
  }
}
}
```

I expect to get one dialog each time when there is an error.

Comment: Facing the same issue, can't find any documentation on this

Comment: Move the initialisation to main() instead of 'didChangeAppLifecycleState' and it fixed my issue.